# Visual Studio 2010 Premium is giving me a "Cannot Create Window" error!

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I first launched the Visual Studio (I **just** installed it) I choose the default programming layout (Visual C#/Visual Basic.NET/ F#/etc) as **Web Development**. It gave some error that it couldn't find the layout scheme or something and now it says Cannot Open Window.

Is there some way to reset the selected layout option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a similar problem with Visual Studio 2010 Express - restarting the computer solved it.

Answer (score 4):

I has the same error when I installs MySql Net Connector mysql-connector-net-6.3.4.msi
I think that this installer corrupt my VS 2010. But NOT.

Previous, I uninstall MySql Connector 6.3.2 and edit machine.config... this was the error!

```
<system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <!-- !!! añadido a mano para poderlo usar en VS2010
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net
                Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory,
                MySql.Data, Version=6.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/> -->
            <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.3.5" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"/></DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

The logic comments not is OK. Then, I erase all commented code and VS2010 come to the live, again!

Answer (score 1):

In my lab the Visual Basic was working fine last semester, but this semester got that "Cannot create the Window" message. After trying reinstalling the VB, Visual Studio, .Net, and other things always got same message. Found a site that mentioned missing windowscodecs.dll file in the windows\system32 directory, but I had the file. Found a different date on file on machines witch the VB was working. Copied the newer windowscodecs.dll file, and that got rid of the problem, but later found I also had to copy the windowscodecsext.dll file as well.

Am now doing a comparison between the two systmes using sigcheck on all the files in system32. Have found a large number that report the Signing date: 12:07 PM 4/14/2008, but the other system has Signing date:   12:13 PM 4/14/2008. Haven't checked the actual contents to see how different the files are. Would be nice if there was a method to check and update to the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Similar error message here when starting up a freshly installed VS2010 Premium.

I had copy pasted stuff from old machine.config, but accidentally left out one Section-definition. Fixed by adding the missing definition into configSections-block.

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be due to some issue in machine.config. Try to replace the config with the original and try.
This resolved for me.